# setOf filtering using a list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter

I'm trying to make a filtering in a list by another list of Values Ex

I want to make this

```
  selectedAreasList = ListOf(1,2,3)

  initialItemProductList.filter { it.areaId in setOf(selectedAreasList) }
```

instead

```
  initialItemProductList.filter { it.areaId in setOf(1,2,3) }
```

Because I don't know the number of items that my list will have

Comment: You don't strictly _need_ a set to call `in`; it would work with `in selectedAreasList` directly.  But most Set implementations are much more efficient at this (as they can look up the hash code directly instead of scanning through each time), so it's usually a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setOf` on a list, use the existing [`toSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/to-set.html) function defined for all `Sequence`s:

```kotlin
selectedAreasList = listOf(1, 2, 3)
// make a set before the filter to avoid repeatedly making a set
selectedAreasSet = selectedAreasList.toSet()
initialItemProductList.filter { id.areaId in selectedAreasSet }
```

Comment: like a charm... Thanks dude

Comment: I think you've mis spelled collection with sequence, although it is defined for sequences as well :)